# Image is not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to bind my image control with sql database. I am saving my image path in sql database and i am retrieving image path from database.When i check through breakpoint then its shows me the path of image but image is not binding with it here is my code

```
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("~/Pics/");
        string serverfilename = Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fullpath = Path.Combine(imagepath, serverfilename);
        string path = "~\\Pics\\" + serverfilename;
        //string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
        //string path = Server.MapPath("~/Pics/") + filename;

        AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(fullpath);
        //  FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert findfriend values('" + path + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand GetImage = new SqlCommand("select * from findfriend where name='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        GetImage.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(GetImage);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Image1.ImageUrl  = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add the image to the page.

```
Page.Controls.Add(yourImage);
```

If you have an already existing image then check if the image is uploaded and exists in the directory.

Comment: Server Response Error: 'Unknown Server error'
i get this error when i do it

Comment: my image is uploading succesfully and it is exists in directory too

Comment: Debug and print the value of ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString(); and see if it correct path

Comment: Change the path from '\' to '\\' and store it. Make sure it shows like this when you debug the value "~\\Pics\\download-icon.png"..

Comment: Guys check this out when i check my source its give me this 
<img id="Image1" src="" style="height:295px;width:338px;border-width:0px;" />

i check my html source after debug my application its path is retrieving but in src its display blank

Answer (score 0):

Database usually identifies the Path in this format:

```
string path="Images/Yourfolder/imagename".
```

Do not add "~" while saving into database.

ex: `string path="~/Images/..."`

Just try to change the path while you are going to save it in database.

If the path that is going to be save has  "//" or reverse slash "\" then it will not identify the folder. Jus save and check with the format I mentioned above.

I have jus used below code to retrieve file from fileupload control and then store the newpath in a separate string and pass it to database.

```
filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName);
               uploadedFile.SaveAs(filepath);
               newpath = "/Images/Gallery/" + uploadedFile.FileName;
```

Comment: The database doesn't identify any path. A string (varchar and all the variant) is a string. If, in his context, storing a path with `~/` makes sense, it doesn't matter.

Comment: its gives me this path 
Pics/Combineezyshop copy.png
but when i check source of my page then image src attribute is emplty

Comment: @SimonBelanger.. In my case also I was having the same issue and the problem was quite same.. n I jus had this solution to save the path into database.

Comment: i also save the path in database but in src it display blank @Kaushik

Comment: I have edited my answer check it... Just tel me how you are retrieving it back from database.. Can you add the code???